# What is uniform continuity geometrically

Tags: real-analysis

I just wonder if someone can give me clear picture because I do understand the technicalities but I still don't have a clear picture of the difference in the geometry between a uniform continuous function and a continuous function.

Comment: Related: [What's the fastest way to tell if a function is uniformly continuous or not?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600623/whats-the-fastest-way-to-tell-if-a-function-is-uniformly-continuous-or-not/) and [Why did mathematicians introduce the concept of uniform continuity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259009/why-did-mathematicians-introduce-the-concept-of-uniform-continuity/).

Comment: very good @AndrewD.Hwang very nice answer on why did mathematicians introduce the concept of uniform continuity !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, continuity is a local property, while uniform continuity is global.

Informally: Say $f$ takes value $y$ at point $x$. Now you perturb the argument $x$ "a little" ($\pm\delta$). Then the values of $f$ around $x$ deviate only by "a little" $\pm\epsilon$ from $y$. For every $\epsilon$ you find such a $\delta$ around $x$. This is continuity at $x$ and it's local, so a continuous function just satisfies this condition independently at every $x$. In contrast, if $f$ is uniformly continuous, the choice of $\delta$ depends only on $\epsilon$, but not on the point: the same $\delta$ works throughout the domain. So given $\epsilon >0$, consider the tunnel given by the graphs of $f\pm\epsilon$. There now exists $\delta>0$ with the property that if you shift the graph of $f$ horizontally by less than $\delta$, then the complete shifted graph is still in the tunnel - this isn't true for merely continuous $f$.

Comment: I see very good !