# If I am asked to prove whether or not a function is uniformly continuous, how can I determine whether it is or is not before constructing the proof?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation, uniform-continuity

Are there a specific series of steps I can take in scratch work where I can determine whether or not continuity is uniform? 
 
I keep having problems where, for instance, I assume the function is uniformly continuous and then try to prove this without any success only to find in the solution sheet that it is not uniformly continuous and I have been going down the wrong path.

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600623/81360) to be helpful

Comment: Is it a continuous function on a non-closed real interval?